# Change the color of the ons-back-button

Tags: onsen-ui

I am trying to figure out how to override the color of the ons-back-button element. I have tried using the modifier:

Thick Button

and create my own style but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change back-button color you can modify ".toolbar-button--quiet" CSS class like this: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/gpPGaP

```
.toolbar-button--quiet {
   color: red;
}
```

For the next time, just right click on the element you want to check and select "Inspect element" or something similar. You will find the class that applies the color or anything you need.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If it was useful for you, please, consider marking it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried being more specific? anyway you can use !important at the end of the styling and it WILL apply, but "!important" is not recommended.